# After Effects : shortcut for next keyframe on current layer?

Tags: after-effects, keyframes

I know about the *J* and *K* shortcuts for the previous/next (visible) keyframe on the timeline.
I was wondering if there was something similar to reach the previous/next keyframe **on the current layer**.
Seems [it exists for Flash](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/564410) (Animate CC) but can't find anything about it in After Effects.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: I use the Page Up/Page Down keys to jump to the past/next frame.

Comment: Yeah, but that is to reach the next frame, not keyframe...

Comment: Doesn't exist and I wish it did. I've been requesting it for as long as I've been using AE.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a shortcut for this.

Here are a couple of 'near alternatives' that might help:

1. The keyframe navigator arrows on the property will jump you from one keyframe to the next on that property alone.

2. Drag the playhead while holding shift to snap to keyframes.